# Spawn Perl script as a process with particular name

Tags: windows, perl, exec

I need a Perl script to spawn itself with an arbitrary name, i.e. so that *the rest of OS* will see it as e.g. "aaa.exe".  I had impression that this is possible to do in Perl but now I'm not sure.

I'm using Strawberry Perl 5.14, 32-bit build, on Windows 7 amd64.

Here's what I tried and does not work:

```
#!perl -w
# spawnself.pl

if ($ARGV[0]) {
    my $name = ($ARGV[0]);
    system {"perl"} $name, $0;
} else {
    print "running as $^X, PID is $$\n";
    print "press Enter to quit...\n";
    my $trash = <>;
}
```

I composed this based on example from [exec perldoc page](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) (system page links there): `exec {'/bin/csh'} '-sh';`, where, IIUC, the goal is to make /bin/csh think it is "-sh", though I'm not sure if that is also supposed to make csh look like "-sh" from the outside. Plus, it's UNIX example, while I'm on Windows.

I'd like to have a script, which being run (from command line) as `spawnself.pl aaa.exe` would spawn itself, printing `running as aaa.exe, PID is 1234`, and looking into Task manager would show this program as "aaa.exe".  However, my snippet as well as the rest of the world still sees itself as "perl.exe":

- in Task manager, process 1234 is still named "perl.exe", so it prints
  `running as C:\path\to\my\perl.exe, PID is 1234`

**What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please shed some light on this?**

Comment: After some research, I have found the problem with `running as spawnper.pl` -- I have misunderstood `$0`, I'm editing the Q to filter this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quite ugly, though working, hack:

```
#!perl -w
#spawnself-ugly.pl

use File::Copy;

if ($ARGV[0]) {
    my $name = ($ARGV[0]);
    copy($^X, $name);
    my @args = ($name, $0);
    system @args;
} else {
    print "running as $^X, PID is $$\n";
    print "press Enter to quit...\n";
    my $trash = <>;
}
```

I actually make a copy of perl.exe and run that one, so finally I simply *am running "aaa.exe"*, so there's no need to lie about anything.